# How to bind list values(array) in Viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here i am getting values in viewbag but i am unable to bind the values to fields.And this is my code

```
@foreach (RankedServices.Business.UIModels.Services cc in ViewBag.selectedCommonCriteria)
                    {
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-12">Awards:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Awards" id="Awards" placeholder="Enter Awards" value="@cc.SelectedCC[0].Awards"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-12">Certifications:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Certifications" id="Certifications" placeholder="Enter Certifications" value="@cc.SelectedCC[0].Certifications" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-12">Associations:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Associations" id="Associations" placeholder="Associations" value="@cc.SelectedCC[0].Associations"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-12">Share your areas of expertise and how you can best help customers:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="AdditionalInfo" id="AdditionalInfo" placeholder="Please tell your customers about your interests, specialities and expertise" rows="2" value="@cc.SelectedCC[0].AdditionalInfo"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

And i am getting error : "Cannot implicitly convert type 'RankedServices.Business.UIModels.Services' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

How should i bind the vlaues.

Comment: Are you sure that a `ViewBag.selectedCommonCriteria` contains a collection, not a single object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `ViewBag.selectedCommonCriteria` is an `IEnumerable` of type `Services` then you can do this:

```
@foreach (RankedServices.Business.UIModels.Services cc in (IEnumerable<RankedServices.Business.UIModels.Services>)ViewBag.selectedCommonCriteria)
```

You're using a `ViewBag` which is a dynamic object so in order to use it for anything other than what every object can do (for example `ToString()`) you must cast it to it's appropriate type.